# Reliable calculation of overriden culture-specific resources in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, resx, resourcemanager

It might be a bit hard to guess from the title what I mean, so let me elaborate.

I have an application that makes use of resources (resx) for translations. I have standard `Strings.resx` file with all strings, and `Strings.xx-XX.resx` files overriding them in specific `xx-XX` culture. Initial `Strings.resx` file has `X` number of strings, where culture-specific `Strings.xx-XX.resx` file might have less or equal than `X` number of strings.

I'm trying to code a function that will be able to reliably calculate how many strings are overriden in that language, which compared to initial number can give me a nice overall translation percentage.

For example, we have 10 strings overall, 6 strings in `es-ES` culture. When `es-ES` user launches application, he'll get a message that `es-ES` translation is completed in 60%.

So far I managed to code something like this:

```
ushort defaultResourceSetCount = 0;
ResourceSet defaultResourceSet = Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), true, true);
if (defaultResourceSet != null) {
    defaultResourceSetCount = (ushort) defaultResourceSet.Cast<object>().Count();
}

ushort currentResourceSetCount = 0;
ResourceSet currentResourceSet = Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, false);
if (currentResourceSet != null) {
    currentResourceSetCount = (ushort) currentResourceSet.Cast<object>().Count();
}

if (currentResourceSetCount < defaultResourceSetCount) {
    // This is our percentage that we want to calculate and show to user
    float translationCompleteness = currentResourceSetCount / (float) defaultResourceSetCount;
}
```

The above code works, but has a lot of dialect limitations that I want to solve. It basically works only for very generic case of having specific culture such as `es-ES` and `Strings` file in that specific culture as well - if user uses something else, such as `es-UY`, he'll get a fallback from .NET of `es-ES`, but that won't work for our calculation. I could switch `tryParents` boolean in `GetResourceSet()` to `true`, but then I'd always get a fallback in form on `en-US` strings declared in original `Strings` file, so we'd always have 100% translation progress, even if user picked totally different culture.

So basically, with our example of 10 resources in `Strings.resx`, and 6 resources in `Strings.es-ES.resx`, following thing should happen:

- We get 100% completion when using `en-US` culture.
- We get 100% completion when using `en-GB` culture, since it falls back to `en-US`, and we have that one covered.
- We get 60% completion when using `es-ES` culture.
- We get 60% completion when using `es-UY` culture, because .NET considers `es`, and then `es-ES` as a fallback. Notice that we don't have `es`, but `es-ES` declared.
- We get 0% completion when using `zh-CN`, even if deepest fallback is `en-US` that we have covered.

I want to solve this problem in the best way, and I'm not quite sure what **is** that best way - I thought that simply getting number of resources would work, and it does, but not for dialects, and trying all parents doesn't work either, since it'd always result in `en-US`. On the other hand, I want to assume that any fallback that is better than `Strings.resx` can be considered as translated, because `es-ES` is totally fine for `es-UY` user, but `en-US` is bad for `zh-CN`. On the other hand, `en-US` is totally fine for `en-GB` user.

Maybe I could in some way compare both `ResourceSet`s with `tryParents` set and compare which strings are different? It'd need to be reference comparison though, as it's totally possible that some strings might have same translation in two different languages. Is it even possible?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Assuming the en-US is your original strings and is your 100 percent case:  I have taken a strategy of comparing the Values of the strings across cultures and if they are non zero length and do not have key words like “TODO” “REVIEW” “NOT DONE” I compare them to the original en-US.  If they are different and non-zero then they are probably done.  If they are the same value as the en-US then they are “not done”.  This is because they all started with the en-US values in every resource file.   I also compare byte count and length to quantify obvious oddballs or blatant screen resize issues.

Comment: @SqlSurfer This is nice, but I assume you compare actual strings value representation? In this case it sadly won't work for me, since I have many strings that actually are included for translation only for RTL language cases, and they're exactly the same in 90% of languages, so something like "{0} V{1}" exists in all languages apart from Hebrew, where it's "{1} V{0}" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I came up with regarding this issue:

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("en")) {
    return;
}

ResourceSet defaultResourceSet = Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), true, true);
if (defaultResourceSet == null) {
    return;
}

HashSet<DictionaryEntry> defaultStringObjects = new HashSet<DictionaryEntry>(defaultResourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>());
if (defaultStringObjects.Count == 0) {
    return;
}

ResourceSet currentResourceSet = Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
if (currentResourceSet == null) {
    return;
}

HashSet<DictionaryEntry> currentStringObjects = new HashSet<DictionaryEntry>(currentResourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>());
if (currentStringObjects.Count >= defaultStringObjects.Count) {
    // Either we have 100% finished translation, or we're missing it entirely and using en-US
    HashSet<DictionaryEntry> testStringObjects = new HashSet<DictionaryEntry>(currentStringObjects);
    testStringObjects.ExceptWith(defaultStringObjects);

    // If we got 0 as final result, this is the missing language
    // Otherwise it's just a small amount of strings that happen to be the same
    if (testStringObjects.Count == 0) {
        currentStringObjects = testStringObjects;
    }
}

if (currentStringObjects.Count < defaultStringObjects.Count) {
    float translationCompleteness = currentStringObjects.Count / (float) defaultStringObjects.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("Do something with translation completeness: " + translationCompleteness);
}
```

It requires only two fairly nice assumptions:

1. Current culture resource set can't have more resources than our default (en-US) culture, this will be the case always when only doing translations.
2. If we have 100% finished translation, we must have at least 1 translated resource that has different representation than original default string, otherwise there is no way to say whether this is intended translated resource set, or default one pulled from en-US.

I'm very happy with this solution.